# SQL DB2 - arithmetic overflow (cannot multiply 3 columns together)

Tags: casting, type-conversion, db2, arithmetic-expressions

I am trying to multiply 3 columns by each other, but I keep receiving an arithmetic overflow error. 2 columns multiplied by each other are fine, but when I try to multiply another, I receive the error.

```
select
account AS ACCOUNT,
amount * fee AS "TOTAL AMOUNT",
(amount * fee) * rate AS "FINAL AMOUNT"
```

In this code, the FINAL AMOUNT does not compute. I thought it might be cast or convert or my syntax, but I'm not sure. The first field (amount), is stored as decimal (24,6), and the fee and rate fields are stored as decimal (15,9)

Please help!

Comment: decimal(15,9) has only 6 pre-comma digits, decimal(24,6) has 18. Have you tried to change the data type for "final amount"?

Comment: What are the actual values that cause the exception? If your data exceeds the data type range, you'll have to choose a different data type or truncate the data.

Comment: ....what currency are you dealing with where 10^18 is a viable amount, Zimbabwean dollars?  The world economy is estimated to be around 8*10^14 or 10^15 (depends on measure) in US dollars...

Answer (score 0):

Decimal arithmetic follows certain rules...

Multiplication and division in particular can greatly increase the precision and scale of your results.

> **Decimal arithmetic in SQL**
>    The following formulas define the precision and scale of the result of decimal operations in SQL.
>
> The symbols p and s denote the precision and scale of the first operand
>   and the symbols p' and s' denote the precision and scale of the second
>   operand. The symbol mp denotes the maximum precision. The value of mp
>   is 63 if:
>   - either p or p' is greater than 31, or
>   - a value of 63 was explicitly specified for the maximum precision. Otherwise, the value of mp is 31.
>   The symbol ms denotes the maximum scale. The default
>   value of ms is 31. ms can be explicitly set to any number from 0 to
>   the maximum precision.
>   **Multiplication**
>   The precision of the result of multiplication is min (mp,p+p') and the scale is min(ms,s+s').

**note mp of 63 and ms of 31 is possibly specific to Db2 for i v5.4+ ...your platform/version may be different**

So for your columns (p,s)
Amount(24,6)
fee (15,9)
rate (15,9)

amount * fee = (39,15) * rate = (54,24) ...

What are the actual values you're dealing with, is it possible that your results have more than (52-24) = 30 digits to the left of the decimal?

I suspect you don't need 24 decimal places...

Take a look at `TRUNC()` or `CAST()` to trim decimal positions, possibly in conjunction with `ROUND()`.